# How to change the app theme programmatically by selecting the Dark Mode from settings app without restarting the app in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on Xamarin.Android project and trying to change the app theme based on mode selection from Settings. How can we change the app theme programmatically by selecting the Dark Mode from settings app without restarting the app. I've added `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.UiMode` to not restart the app after changing the mode. Any suggestions on this.